# The spectrum of symmetric givens operation on square non zero matrix.

Tags: matrices, measure-theory

I have to figure out why in case of square matrix $A$ $\sigma(A) =  σ(A_1)$, where $A_1 = GAG^T$ and $G$ is a Givens matrix.
Any tips and help would be very appreciated since I spent a lot of time on research without any answer.

Comment: What is a Givens matrix?

Comment: It is a matrix which will compute a particular Givens rotation on a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G$ is real orthogonal. Hence $GAG^T=GAG^{-1}$ is similar to $A$ and they have identical spectra.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is perfect.